# Get some text after the first h1 tag of the page

Tags: jquery

How can I get the text after the first `h1` tag of the page? On the page there will be some text after the h1 tag. That text can be the HTML list or simple plain text.

So I want to get some text, that can be about two sentences or we can limit by character counter after the first H1 tag of the page, if there is no text the will get the `H1` tag text.

How will I do this using jQuery?

**My current HTML is:**

```html
<div class="main_content">
  <h1>H1 tag text</h1>
  <div class="other_text">
    This is <b>some</b> text.
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case I need `This is some text`.

Or it can be like the following as well:

```html
<div class="main_content">
  <h1>H1 tag text</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>first element</li>
    <li>second element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this case I need the first two li's contents.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide your current HTML and show the expected output.

Comment: have you tried something ? ... methods like next and first will help U

Comment: put it in the span and give it id ... you can access to that text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you can do in this case is to make use of `.next()` and `.text()`. So, let's try with both of your cases.

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($("h1").next().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_content">
  <h1>H1 tag text</h1>
  <div class="other_text">
    This is <b>some</b> text.
  </div>
</div>
```

And for the next case, let's try with the same code:

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($("h1").next().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_content">
  <h1>H1 tag text</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>first element</li>
    <li>second element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps and works! `:)`

Comment: can we add some character limit to this. as it will get all the lis

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, you can use `.substr(100)` or something like that.